# How to add a reference to primary key of same table twice in a table in postgres in rails5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, sqlite, foreign-keys

I am using Rails 5.0.1 for web development and deploying my app on Heroku. I am using postgreSQL as my database.

I have a table called Users and a table called Friends.
In friends table I want to store the user Id twice, for example to indicate that user id 1 is friend of user id 2.

How can I do this?

So far I have tried following things with no success:

**Attempt 1:**

migration file:

```
create_table :friends do |t|
  t.references :user, foreign_key: true
  t.references :user, foreign_key: true
  t.timestamps
end
```

Model:

```
class Friend < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :friend1, :foreign_key => :friend1_id, :class_name => 'User'
  belongs_to :friend2, :foreign_key => :friend2_id, :class_name => 'User'
end
```

**Attempt 2:**

migration file:

```
create_table :friends do |t|
  t.references :friend1_id, foreign_key: true
  t.references :friend2_id, foreign_key: true
  t.timestamps
end
```

Model:

```
class Friend < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :friend1, :foreign_key => :user_id, :class_name => 'User'
  belongs_to :friend2, :foreign_key => :user_id, :class_name => 'User'
end
```

Is there something wrong with the way I am modeling it? or, can this be done in a better/easier way?
My requirement is to store information about a user and his friends. A user can have multiple friends.

PS: Before deploying on Heroku/PostgreSQL, I was running the application on my local system using sqlite3, the scripts seemed to be working fine there, but they don't work on Heroku/PostgreSQL now.

Comment: Why do you not use has_many relationship? User has_many Friends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have mostly the right pieces, but need to recombine them eg this should work:

```
class Friend < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :friend1, :foreign_key => :friend1_id, :class_name => 'User'
  belongs_to :friend2, :foreign_key => :friend2_id, :class_name => 'User'
end
```

if your columns are `friend_1`/`friend_2`

```
create_table :friends do |t|
  t.integer :friend1_id
  t.integer :friend2_id
  t.timestamps
end
```

You may need to manually add foreign-keys though, as I don't think rails supports the differently-named keys.

Note: these other two things you tried definitely won't work because Rails finds `user_id` to be ambiguous... or repeated.

Answer (score 0):

I did a search in Github, and found this. Hope helpful:

*app/models/user.rb*

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :friends, join_table: :friends_users
has_many :outgoing_friend_requests, class_name: FriendRequest
has_many :incoming_friend_requests, class_name: FriendRequest,
```

foreign_key: :friend_id

*app/models/friend.rb*

```
class Friend < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = :users

  has_and_belongs_to_many :users, join_table: :friends_users
end
```

*app/models/friend_request.rb*

```
class FriendRequest < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friend
end
```

Here is the [Repo Link](https://github.com/Codaisseur/friends-demo)